# How to get a property from array via laravel collections?

Tags: laravel, collections, eloquent

I got an Order object which has many-to-many relation with products:

```
public function products() {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'order_products')
                   ->withPivot('count', 'price');
   }
```

I accept in request an array with products, then I should attach it to the order. But if I got an array, not collection, then how should I do this right way? I can do it via loop in `$request->products`, but it seems to be wrong for me.

To be exact, I have an array:

```
$products = [
  ['id' => 4, 'count' => 5],
  ['id'=>5, 'count' => 3]        
];
```

How to do an `$order->products->attach()` without any loop?

Answer (score 3):

Both `attach` and `detach` accept an array of ids:

```
$ids = collect($request->products)->pluck('id');

$order->products()->attach($ids);
```

Comment: also `Illuminate\Support\Arr::pluck` and `array_pluck` for completeness :)